# Detecting plagiarism for data sets

Tags: plagiarism

Does anyone know of a program that can detect plagiarism for data sets? I am mainly thinking of detecting "already existing" numbers.

Do existing plagiarism software also detect for number plagiarism?

Comment: According to a editor-in-chief's assertion, commercial softwares of journals might even detect such kinds of plagiarism.

Comment: Do you have examples of names of such softwares?

Comment: "iThenticate" is the most famous one... I've heard of "Plag Tracker" in view of the efficiency and accuracy...

Comment: I believe that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api) might help if you want to develop your own "detector". It should be done in Java, if you know any programming it would take less than a day the implementation.

Comment: That page is no longer in use, it seems. But I appreciate your contribution none the less.

"Update since November 2010 (2 months after the above answer), the public search webservice has become deprecated (and the last day on which the service was offered was September 29, 2014). Your best bet is now querying http://www.google.com/search directly along with a honest user agent and then parse the result using a HTML parser."

Comment: Does anyone know how effective these programs are at detecting plagiarized numbers only?